# LINQ Min(dates)

Tags: linq, min

I have a daft 3rd party who provide me with multiple items which each contain dates(DateFrom) in string formatted yyyyMMdd.

I am trying to get the soonest date from these using Linq as follows:

```
 _providerRecords.Policy.Min(c =>  System.DateTime.ParseExact(c.DateFrom, "yyyyMMdd",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

However this keeps returning me the 1st record each time. Can anyone see what the flip I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, something else...? Note that due to the format used, you don't actually need to parse the date at all - just using an ordinal comparison will find the earliest date.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahah, good catch on the string format.

Comment: Silly question, was simply down to my mind playing tricks on me regarding dates. Works a treat........ My date format is in a constant in case the 3rd party decide in their infinite wisdom to amend in future revision of their output :-) Cheers folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Min was working as expected, my late afternoon head caused me the cockup.